# Alternative to window function in MariaDB 10.1

Tags: syntax, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have a windows function (`over`, `partitioned by`) in my code:

```
FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.id, 
                                     wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                                     post_title, 
                                     post_type, 
                                     meta_value, 
                                     Row_number() 
                                       OVER( 
                                         partition BY post_title 
                                         ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn
```

but apparently this isn't supported on MariaDB before 10.2 (-I am using 10.1).  Could someone please suggest alternative code which is both efficient and works on MariaDB 10.1 also?

[dbfiddle provided, unfortunately with only MariaDB 10.2 as the oldest; can't test 10.1 directly here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e3d0476302015f8cbd0f5bcd600334ce)

> ```
> create table wp_posts (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_title varchar(30),
>   post_type varchar(30)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table wp_postmeta (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_id integer,
>   meta_key varchar(30) not null default '_regular_price',
>   meta_value integer not null
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_posts (post_title, post_type) values
> ('Apple Pie','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Shepards Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Plate','Not a Product'),
> ('Bucket','Not a Product'),
> ('Chequebook','Not a Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_value) values
> (1,10),
> (2,5),
> (3,9),
> (4,8),
> (5,11),
> (6,12),
> (7,10),
> (8,6),
> (9,1),
> (10,1),
> (11,7),
> (12,2),
> (13,2);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- Deleting all duplicate products in wp_posts table 
> DELETE FROM wp_posts 
> WHERE  id IN (SELECT id 
>               FROM   (SELECT id, 
>                              post_title, 
>                              post_type, 
>                              meta_value 
>                       FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.id, 
>                                      wp_postmeta.post_id, 
>                                      post_title, 
>                                      post_type, 
>                                      meta_value, 
>                                      Row_number() 
>                                        OVER( 
>                                          partition BY post_title 
>                                          ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn 
>                               FROM   wp_postmeta 
>                                      JOIN wp_posts 
>                                        ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
>                               WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
>                                      AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
>                              ) t 
>                       WHERE  t.rn <> 1) AS aliasx);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e3d0476302015f8cbd0f5bcd600334ce)*

Comment: Tell us the intent of the query.

Comment: There are two tables `wp_posts` containing the `post_title` column and `wp_postmeta`, containing the `meta_value` column.  Both tables have an integer incremented column (`wp_posts.ID`, `wp_postmeta.post_id`) which allows them to be linked/joined (1 matches with 1, 2 matches with 2, etc.).  `post_title` and  `meta_value` are not necessarily unique, however, I want to to make aggregate selections grouped by `post_title`.  Always select the lowest `meta_value`, and then select the corresponding `wp_posts.ID` for that `meta_value`

Comment: Follow the [groupwise-maximum] tag for lots of tips on achieving that.